# Find indexed sets $A_n$, $n\in\Bbb N$, with intersection $\{-1,0,1\}$ and union $\Bbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set notation these two last conditions are
$$\bigcap_nA_n=\{-1, 0, 1\}$$
$$\bigcup_nA_n=\Bbb Z$$
Not quite sure what it's asking or even what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: You are asked to find sets, such that their union is $\Bbb Z$, but the only elements which appear in *all* of these sets, are $-1,0,$ and $1$.

Comment: Note that there are infinitely many correct answers.  **Be Creative!**

Answer (score 1):

Here are two rather natural answers:

$A_1 = \{-1,0,1\}$

$A_n = \Bbb Z$ for all $n\geq 2$

---

And another:

$A_n = \{z\in \Bbb Z~:~|z|\leq n\}$.   In other words, $A_1=\{-1,0,1\},A_2=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}, A_3 = \{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\},\dots$

---

The point being that whatever answer you use, you must have it so that $\{-1,0,1\}$ is a subset of everything and for every integer there is at least one set which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
$$A_1=\{-1,0,1,-2\}$$
$$A_2=\{-1,0,1,2\}$$
$$A_3=\{-1,0,1,-3\}$$
$$A_4=\{-1,0,1,3\}\text{, etc.}$$
In general:
$$A_n=\{-1,0,1,(-1)^n(\lceil n/2\rceil+1)\}$$
The first three terms ensure that the intersection of all $A_n$ is $\{-1,0,1\}$. The final term, as $n$ counts from 1 upwards, enumerates the rest of the integers à la [OEIS A001057](https://oeis.org/A001057), so the union of all $A_n$ becomes exactly the integers.